# How to derive the Unruh effect (or the thermofield double state) from the path integral?

Tags: general-relativity, hilbert-space, acceleration, qft-in-curved-spacetime, unruh-effect

I have been reading about the path integral approach to deriving the thermofield double state for the Minkowski vacuum in terms of the Rindler states:
\begin{equation}
\left|0_{M}(t=0)\right\rangle=\sum_{n} \frac{e^{-\frac{\beta}{2} E_{n}}}{\sqrt{Z(\beta)}}\left|n_{R}\right\rangle \otimes\left[\Theta\left|n_{L}\right\rangle\right].
\end{equation}
According to https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.09869, this result can be derived by considering
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\left\langle\phi_{M} \mid 0_{M}(t=0)\right\rangle & \propto \int_{\phi(\theta=-\pi)=\phi_{I}}^{\phi(\theta=0)=\phi_{D}} D \phi e^{-I_{E}} \\
& \propto\left\langle\phi_{R}\left|e^{-\pi H^{R}}\right| \phi_{L}\right\rangle
\end{aligned}.
\end{equation}
But my other reference is https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1231, which claims we should be studying
\begin{equation}
\left\langle\phi_{L} \phi_{R} \mid \Omega\right\rangle \propto\left\langle\phi_{R}\left|e^{-\pi K_{R}} \Theta\right| \phi_{L}\right\rangle_{L}
\end{equation}
Which is different because of the CPT operator $\Theta$. (As far as I can tell $K_R$ and $H^R$ are the same thing).

Which of these is correct?

Answer (score 1):

It seems I was confused by notation here. After all in the first expression the $| \phi_L \rangle $ can only be evolved by $H^R$ and projected onto $| \phi_R \rangle$ if it is in the right-Rindler wedge states. So $| \phi_L \rangle $ must live in the same space as $| \phi_R \rangle $ which can be achieved by applying $\Theta$ to a left-Rindler wedge state.